# Laravel Exceptions: throwing error when not attaching nullable input file

Tags: php, laravel, try-catch

I have a form when the user submits `lostFound` model. The validation request is as follows:

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'LFImage' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,jpg,png,gif,webp', // TODO: Read about 'Sometimes'.
            'handoverStatement' => 'nullable|image|mimes:jpeg,jpg,png,gif,webp',
        ];
    }
```

So, one attached is required (`LFImage`) and the other isn't (`handoverStatement`).

I created a dynamic image upload action:

```
class UploadImageAction implements UploadImageContract {
    public function handle(Request $request, $image, $imageLocation)
    {
        $storedImage = ($request->hasFile($image))
        ? $request->file($image)->store($imageLocation)
        : NULL;

        if(!$storedImage)
        {
           throw new ImageUploadException('Something went wrong with the image upload.' . $storedImage);
        }

        return $storedImage;
    }
}
```

Then calling it in the controller `store()` with `try, catch`:

```
// Add new Record.
public function store(LostFoundRequest $request, LostFoundService $lostFoundService, UploadImageContract $uploadImageAction)
{
    try {
        $LFImage = $uploadImageAction->handle($request, 'LFImage', 'lostFound/lostItems');
        $handoverStatement = $uploadImageAction->handle($request, 'handoverStatement', 'lostFound/handoverStatements');
        $lostFoundService->storeLostFound($request, $LFImage, $handoverStatement);
        return redirect('data-entry/lost-and-found')->with('success', 'Item Added Successfully');
    } catch (ImageUploadException $exception) {
        // Handle upload image error
        return back()->withErrors($exception->getMessage());
    } catch (LostFoundException $exception) {
        // Handle lostfound created error
        return back()->withErrors('lostFound', $exception->getMessage());
    } catch (\Throwable $exception) {
        throw $exception;
    }

}
```

Every time I submit the form without attaching `handoverStatement` I get the exception error (The data isn't saved, yet `LFImage` is uploaded to the dir).

What am I missing here?

Note: the `ImageUploadException` class doesn't have any methods:

```
<?php

namespace App\Exceptions;

use Exception;

class ImageUploadException extends Exception {}
```

Comment: That did nothing, what were you trying to do?

Comment: Did you import the ImageUploadException correctly with a use-statement in the top of controller?

Comment: @thephper Yes: ```use App\Exceptions\ImageUploadException;```